# Convert Array2D<byte> to InputArray

Tags: c#, opencv

How can I convert a Convert `Array2D<byte>` to `InputArray` (OutputArray) in OpenCVSharp? I need to resize my img:

```
Array2D<byte> img;
scaledImg = Cv2.Resize(img, scaledImg, new Size( (int)(img.Columns * imgScale), (int)(img.Rows * imgScale)) );
```